# how to convert a android service application to jar

Tags: android, android-service

I have a application "A" which consists of only a service and will be used by my other application(s).
I have another application "B" which has Activity and which uses Service from "A" through AIDL.

My question,
Is it possible to have application "A" as a library and included in application "B" ?
If yes, how to do that ? 
if not, why ?

-regards,
Manju

Answer (score 0):

After you build application "A", go to project `bin` folder and copy jar-file to "B" project `libs` folder.